# Deck of cards using zip

Tags: python

Im trying to make a deck of cards using zip,
but what i got is the object code?
"<zip object at 0x0000025763A32200>, <zip object at 0x0000025763A32240>,...."

```
suits = ['diamond','club','heart','spade']
value = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
deck = [zip(suit, val) for val in value for suit in suits]
print(deck)
```

How do i make it as a list of tuples? (using zip)

```
print(deck)
output :
[('A','diamond'),('A','club')....('K','diamond')]
```

Comment: Don't use zip, you don't need it

Comment: You don't need `zip()` at all here, just `deck = [(val, suit) for ...`.

Comment: [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is also handy here: `list(product(value, suits))`

Comment: Well basically im learning how to use zip, thats why im trying to make a deck using zip method..

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessary to use zip? You can get what you want just by not using zip and leaving your code as it is, saving a tuple(val,suit), not zipping them:

```py
>>> deck = [(val,suit) for val in value for suit in suits]
>>> print(deck)
[('A', 'diamond'), ('A', 'club'), ('A', 'heart'), ('A', 'spade'), ('2', 'diamond'), ('2', 'club'), ('2', 'heart'), ('2', 'spade'), ('3', 'diamond'), ('3', 'club'), ('3', 'heart'), ('3', 'spade'), ('4', 'diamond'), ('4', 'club'), ('4', 'heart'), ('4', 'spade'), ('5', 'diamond'), ('5', 'club'), ('5', 'heart'), ('5', 'spade'), ('6', 'diamond'), ('6', 'club'), ('6', 'heart'), ('6', 'spade'), ('7', 'diamond'), ('7', 'club'), ('7', 'heart'), ('7', 'spade'), ('8', 'diamond'), ('8', 'club'), ('8', 'heart'), ('8', 'spade'), ('9', 'diamond'), ('9', 'club'), ('9', 'heart'), ('9', 'spade'), ('10', 'diamond'), ('10', 'club'), ('10', 'heart'), ('10', 'spade'), ('J', 'diamond'), ('J', 'club'), ('J', 'heart'), ('J', 'spade'), ('Q', 'diamond'), ('Q', 'club'), ('Q', 'heart'), ('Q', 'spade'), ('K', 'diamond'), ('K', 'club'), ('K', 'heart'), ('K', 'spade')]
```

Remember, if you want the order by value the right order in your tuple must be (val,suit), and not (suit,val)

With this simple form you don't need any extra module.

Comment: Well basically im learning how to use zip, trying to make a deck using zip method

Comment: I see, understandable, I would say this is not the best example to use zip, since there is a simpler form to solve this problem. zip will help you if you need to pair objects together, just like [1,2,3] and ['a','b','c'] to get = [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]. Using zip in this problem makes it more complex.

Comment: To get the most out of zip your iterables must be of the same length, in this case values is larger than suits, from here zip is not as suitable as other options. Try to apply it to another use case. You can use zip for different lengths but it will stop once the shortest has been zipped.

Again, this example may not be the best to learn zip, since it adds unnecesary complexity to the solution.

Comment: Is it possible to loop the zip?
for each value in the deck, zipping it with each value in suits..
Is this doable?

Comment: As far as I understand, for this use case no. zip must be used with iterables of the same length, if you iterate through each value you won't be able to pair it with each suit using zip, zip does not work like that. What you need is making all the different combinations, you can use either my solution or itertools for that. Zip is not suitable for this task. The best use case for zip is just pairing n iterables of the same length, here is where you'll get the most out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` won't work for this, but you can use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> deck = list(itertools.product(value, suits))
>>> print(deck)
[('A', 'diamond'), ('A', 'club'), ('A', 'heart'), ('A', 'spade'), ('2', 'diamond'), ('2', 'club'), ('2', 'heart'), ('2', 'spade'), ('3', 'diamond'), ('3', 'club'), ('3', 'heart'), ('3', 'spade'), ('4', 'diamond'), ('4', 'club'), ('4', 'heart'), ('4', 'spade'), ('5', 'diamond'), ('5', 'club'), ('5', 'heart'), ('5', 'spade'), ('6', 'diamond'), ('6', 'club'), ('6', 'heart'), ('6', 'spade'), ('7', 'diamond'), ('7', 'club'), ('7', 'heart'), ('7', 'spade'), ('8', 'diamond'), ('8', 'club'), ('8', 'heart'), ('8', 'spade'), ('9', 'diamond'), ('9', 'club'), ('9', 'heart'), ('9', 'spade'), ('10', 'diamond'), ('10', 'club'), ('10', 'heart'), ('10', 'spade'), ('J', 'diamond'), ('J', 'club'), ('J', 'heart'), ('J', 'spade'), ('Q', 'diamond'), ('Q', 'club'), ('Q', 'heart'), ('Q', 'spade'), ('K', 'diamond'), ('K', 'club'), ('K', 'heart'), ('K', 'spade')]
```

Comment: Well basically im learning how to use zip, trying to make a deck using zip method